# Where can I download the SignalR 2.0.3 Dlls from?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Does anyone know where I can download the SignalR 2.0.3 Dlls?

I installed the packages through NuGet in VS 2013.
It successfully pulled the *.nuspec and *.nupkg files.

This builds fine in VS 2013.
But, I really need to get copies of the actual DLLs to install
into our source tree/build environment.

Does anyone know where I can download these directly from?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download the source code and compile it yourself:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.0.3

I should be as easy as unzip, open with VS and compile in Release mode.